# How to install QUCS (Quite Universal Circuit Software) on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, 13.04

I am having troubles installing qucs, so this is all i have tried without positive results:

1. It is not avilable software center
2. There is no a debian package
3. ppa:fransschreuder1/qucs is not working

I hope you have a solution. Thanks you guys :)

Comment: follow the instructions [here](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/install.html#install_ubuntu) .

Answer (score 4):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/qucs says

> There is no current release of this source package in The Raring
>   Ringtail. You can still report bugs, make translations, and so on, but
>   they might not be used until the package is published.

So, if you want to install qucs on Ubuntu Raring (13.04), please do the following

If you are using 64 bit machine

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/86130584/qucs_0.0.15-1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i qucs_0.0.15-1.1_amd64.deb
```

If you are using 32 bit machine

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/86124276/qucs_0.0.15-1.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i qucs_0.0.15-1.1_i386.deb
```